# How to highlight a line from another figure in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

In the example below (Bokeh 2.3.3), when I hover above one line (Alice's sales), the line width is increased. How can I make the other line (Alice's ratings) wider at the same time?

```py
import random

import bokeh.io
import bokeh.palettes
import bokeh.layouts
import bokeh.plotting

months = list(range(12))
quarters = list(range(4))

sales = {
    'alice': [random.randint(0,100) for _ in months],
    'bob': [random.randint(0,100) for _ in months],
}
ratings = {
    'alice': [random.randint(0,5) for _ in quarters],
    'bob': [random.randint(0,5) for _ in quarters],
}

TOOLS = 'hover'

f1 = bokeh.plotting.figure(title='sales', plot_height=200, tools=TOOLS)
f1.line(months, sales['alice'], name='alice', hover_line_width=3)
f1.line(months, sales['bob'], name='bob', hover_line_width=3)

f2 = bokeh.plotting.figure(title='ratings', plot_height=200,tools=TOOLS)
f2.line(quarters, ratings['alice'], name='alice', hover_line_width=3)
f2.line(quarters, ratings['bob'], name='bob', hover_line_width=3)

# hover callback (?)

bokeh.io.show(bokeh.layouts.gridplot([[f1],[f2]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.
First, you should use the same source, and they are automatically linked.
Second, you could use a tap tool with indices to link to other graph. You could use on_event or js_on_event for TapTool

Finally, why do you using full functions like 'bokeh.io.show'? you could import. Also, for second option, you should use ColumnDataSource

Comment: I tried with the tap tool instead of hover, but was unable to write a custom js callback to select other rendered by name. How can I achieve that? For the imports, I do it that way because I have both bokeh and matplotlib in the same notebook.